# Z-index canvas property

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

everyone)
I need to draw a circle on the canvas background image.
But, unfortunately, background image fully covers the circle, so a user cannot see it. 
There is my code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var background = new Image();
background.src = "img/star-sky.jpg";

// Make sure the image is loaded first otherwise nothing will draw.
background.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(background,0,0);   
}

var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 90;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
context.stroke();

background.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(background,0,0);   
}
```

Please, can you tell me how to use z-index canvas property?

Comment: The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: z-index is for HTML elements, you can not use that on stuff you paint onto your canvas. But the problem here is not even layering on the z-axis, but a _timing_ problem - you paint the background when that image has loaded (why are you assigning _two_ load events for that, btw?), but you paint your circle before that happens. So you got your nice little circle, then the image to be used as background finishes loading, and in that moment you are painting it _over_ the existing circle.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work as you said you wanted, even without the use of z-index.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var background = new Image();
background.src = "http://www.c00lsch00l.eu/Games/AA/stars.png";

// Make sure the image is loaded first otherwise nothing will draw.
background.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
  var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
  var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius = 90;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
  context.stroke();
}



/*background.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(background,0,0);   
}*/
```

```html
<canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
```

What I did: I pasted your code to be executed in background.onload method, after background is loaded and omitted another call of onload (which will cover your yellow circle anyway).

You can also position two canvases on top of one another (use absolute position), then use z-index to display them as you want.
In your case, this was not necessary. Simple order of drawing did the trick.